# User was signing on to Game Center and the game crashed immediately afterwards

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I am unable to find the reason of the crash.  I know that the user was signing on to Game Centre.  However, this was followed by the user starting to play 'MyApp'.  I still can't find the error.  I have read Apple  tech doc and the 2010 video.  Still unable to find the problem.  Please help.

```
Incident Identifier: D3A80086-855D-400D-8102-7D08D04C2A4D
CrashReporter Key:   6b4377c06adbfe5d64bfb9dd348bd73e93859214
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,4
Process:             MyApp [280]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D5470DBE-1FF8-4E06-946B-910AD698DD2D/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          MyApp
Version:             4 (4.86)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-12-26 01:10:15.15 +0400
Launch Time:         2015-12-26 01:06:30.30 +0400
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Breadcrumb Trail: (reverse chronological seconds)
6      logging-started
6      GC TBG: lookForEvent
224    GC Framework: startAuthenticationForExistingPrimaryPlayer


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
6.978571     GameCenterFoundation       0x000000002eb776e1 callAuthHandlerWithError:Setting the Authentication Handler
6.989052     GameCenterFoundation       0x000000002eb886f5 GKMatchMaker: lookForInvite
6.989130     GameCenterFoundation       0x000000002ebb05d9 updateNearbyAdvertising
6.989130     GameCenterFoundation       0x000000002eb88485 finishedAuthenticating: Starting nearby Advertising and looking for invites
6.989724     GameCenterFoundation       0x000000002eb87f49 GKMatchmaker: loadConnectivitySettingsWithCompletionHandler
6.990383     GameCenterFoundation       0x000000002eb77663 Calling AuthenticationHandlerWithError: 0
7.056258     GameCenterUI               0x000000002f8067fd authenticationDidCompleteWithError:Local Player Authenticated, showing Welcome Banner
7.056258     GameCenterUI               0x000000002f8065f7 authenticationDidCompleteWithError being called
214.506726   GameCenterUI               0x000000002f8074e3 authenticationShowSignInUIForLocalPlayer:Showing sign in view controller



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                           0x000e8160 0xce000 + 106848
1   GameCenterFoundation            0x2ebc92c4 __39-[GKDispatchGroup notifyOnQueue:block:]_block_invoke53 + 12
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x228abdd6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x228abdc2 _dispatch_client_callout + 22
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x228b0670 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1532
5   CoreFoundation                  0x22cd0fc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
6   CoreFoundation                  0x22ccf4be __CFRunLoopRun + 1590
7   CoreFoundation                  0x22c21bb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
8   CoreFoundation                  0x22c219ac CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
9   GraphicsServices                0x23e9baf8 GSEventRunModal + 160
10  UIKit                           0x26f0dfb4 UIApplicationMain + 144
11  MyApp                           0x000daa08 0xce000 + 51720
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x228d4872 start + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this exactly same problem.
The apple reviewer report to check if my app is IPv6 compatible.
I reply him that my app use only Game Center to communicate, if this is a IPv6 problem, this should be a Game Center problem.

Anyway, in my experience, testing my app, this only happened when I change from Main Menu to Game Mode menu when the "Game Center Authentication Banner" is opened.

My game is developed in SceneKit and the menus are developed using SpriteKit inside the SceneView on Overlay layer.
To switch menus, I just change the SKScene in SceneView.

Comment: I just had the same experience. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I didn't solved, but after some changes, I submitted again and other reviewer approved my app.
I guess that, when the first reviewer tested my app, the GameCenter network was experiencing some problems, then they believed that was some bug of my App.